# Writing my non-Chinese name in Chinese using Romanization

Tags: romanization

I tried using [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Wu_Chinese) to "romanize" my non-Chinese name into (Wu) Chinese characters.  But when I texted it to my friend in Shanghai, they did said it did not sound the same as my name spelled in Latin (English) characters.  What did I do wrong?  Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this chart?

Comment: "Romanization" means converting some other writing system to Roman characters. So yes, I'd say you're misunderstanding the chart; it lists a few different systems for transcribing Wu in Roman characters, not for converting something else into Wu.

Comment: Ok, but why wouldn't it work in reverse?

Comment: Because this table is specifically using Roman characters to represent the sounds of Wu. It's not concerned with how an unrelated language, like English, might use those letters.

Comment: English uses Roman characters though, and their sounds are pretty standard across languages, all things considered, especially the consonants. I wouldn't it expect it to come out completely different.  And anyway, I double-checked the IPA column when I selected the characters, so it's not really an issue of "Roman characters" at all.

Comment: Let's rephrase the question, and forget about "Roman characters".  Let's remove those columns completely from the chart.  Shouldn't I be able to select Chinese characters using the IPA column and expect them to sound like that?

Comment: Ahh. I think I see where the confusion is coming from. No, because those characters are, to my understanding, just examples of syllables that contain that sound. For example, 好 (the first character listed for `/h/`) is pronounced _hau2_ — a good example of `/h/`, but not a good transcription of `/h/` on its own.

Comment: @Draconis, can you move that to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this chart?

Yes, the purpose of this chart is to help people familiar with Wu transcribe it into Roman characters. The characters given are *examples* of each phoneme, not *equivalents* to them—the writing system isn't an alphabet. So, for instance, 好黑 isn't pronounced *h*: it's pronounced *hau2 heq4* ("good black"), giving two examples of common words containing the `/h/` phoneme.

Comment: So there's no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: There is, but you need to know quite a lot of characters and their pronunciations.

Comment: So could a "reverse Romanization" chart be developed?

Comment: @BlueWhale Yes, you'd just need a table of words with every possible combination of onset, nucleus, and coda, which you could pick from to transcribe your name.

Comment: @BlueWhale Chinese characters represent **syllables**, not phonemes – and many of them can represent more than one syllable depending on context (e.g., in Mandarin, 率 can represent _lü_ or _shuài_, 着 can represent _zhe_, _zhuó_, _zhāo_ or _zháo_, etc.). And Chinese phonotactics are very restrictive: the number of initials, glides, peaks (vowels) and codas is quite limited, and only a subset of their combinations is possible (e.g., initial _f_ exists, vowel _o_ exists, coda _ng_ exists, but _*fong_ does not exist). So to transliterate a name, you’ll need a list of **all possible syllables** ->

Comment: -> in transcription (and with their IPA), and then choose the combination of existing syllables that most closely matches what your name sounds like in English. I don’t speak Wu, but in Mandarin, _Blue Whale_ would probably be best transliterated as _Bulu Weile_ or _Bulu Wei’er_. There’s some additional overhead in that each variant of Chinese has particular characters (and thus syllables) that are particularly common in transliterated names, such as _er_ (尔) in the example above, which is usually used for all syllable-final l’s and r’s.